# Kotlin передать в активити ArrayList<itemClass>

Tags: kotlin, arraylist, android-intent

```
results=ArrayList<resultItem>()
```

мне нужно передать это в другое активити

```
val intent=Intent(this,resultActivity::class.java)
intent.putExtra("results",results)
startActivity(intent)
```

как в другом активити получить этот список? не нашел подходящего метода у интент
пробовал так:

```
var results=ArrayList<resultItem>()
if(intnt.hasExtra("results")){
    results=(ArrayList<resultItem>)intnt.getSerializableExtra("results")
    results=intnt.getParcelableArrayListExtra<resultItem>("results")
}
```

ошибка Type mismatch

Comment: resultItem у вас Serializable или Parcelable? Записывайте явно с помощью putParcelableArrayList(), тогда и читать понятнее как.

Comment: Это просто интересное чтиво по теме: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50114007/5479247

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте этот способ

```
val items = ArrayList<ResultItem>()
val intent = Intent(this, ResultActivity::class.java)
val args = Bundle()
args.putSerializable("ARRAYLIST",items as Serializable);
intent.putExtra("results", args);
startActivity(intent);
```

Во второй Activity:

```
val args = intent.getBundleExtra("BUNDLE") as ArrayList<ResultItem>
```

А еще лучше в объекте ResultItem реализовать интерфейс Parcellable и передать это все с помощью метода:

```
putParcelableArrayList()
```